# C simple program /can you explain me result?

Tags: c

Here is code:

```
char number=4;
while(number<5) number=number-1;
printf("%d" , number);
```

result=127 , why ? can you explain me ? thanks

Comment: Signed integer underflow. Undefined behavior.

Comment: Try `char number=4;
while(number<5)  {number=number-1;
printf("%d " , number); }` for some insight.

Comment: Not really undefined behaviour? edit: oh, ok because `char` might not have exactly 8 bits?

Comment: The question will be more reasonable if you change `char` to `int8_t`. Or, you can ask about the difference between `char` and `int8_t`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, because signed integer overflow is undefined.

Comment: For 2's complement on an 8-bit integer type, subtracting by 1 is the same as adding the binary number `11111111` (which represents -1), and the minimum integer value would be `10000000` (which represents -128). `char` is not defined to use 2's complement arithmetic, but `int8_t` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is set to iterate until number < 5. What happens is the value decrements to 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1 ... -128. When it attempts to subtract one more value, you get a wrap around to the max value the char can hold (8 bits, 127, or 0x7F). At this point, the loop condition is no longer true, so your loop exits. Therefore, your final value after the wrap around is 127.

Comment: There is more to it than that. Starting from the fact the subtraction is performed after integer promotions, and up to the fact that signed integer overflow has an undefined behavior according to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

the condition specified in the `while` is that it should iterate as long as number is less than 5. So it starts off with decrementing, 4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2 and so on.. It goes on till -127 which is least value it can hold, then it wraps around to the the other end of the line which is 127(positive 127). the loop condition now fails, i.e, 127 is not lesser than 5 anymore. Just to observe this behavior, Give the `printf` statement within the `while`  loop, as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
   char number = 4;
   while(number<5){ 
      number=number-1;
      printf("%d||" , number);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

***here is the output:***

> gcc version 4.6.3
>
> 3||2||1||0||-1||-2||-3||-4||-5||-6||-7||-8||-9||-10||-11||-12||-13||-14||-15||-16||-17||-18||-19||-20||-21||-22||-23||-24||-25||-26||-27||-28||-29||-30||-31||-32||-33||-34||-35||-36||-37||-38||-39||-40||-41||-42||-43||-44||-45||-46||-47||-48||-49||-50||-51||-52||-53||-54||-55||-56||-57||-58||-59||-60||-61||-62||-63||-64||-65||-66||-67||-68||-69||-70||-71||-72||-73||-74||-75||-76||-77||-78||-79||-80||-81||-82||-83||-84||-85||-86||-87||-88||-89||-90||-91||-92||-93||-94||-95||-96||-97||-98||-99||-100||-101||-102||-103||-104||-105||-106||-107||-108||-109||-110||-111||-112||-113||-114||-115||-116||-117||-118||-119||-120||-121||-122||-123||-124||-125||-126||-127||-128||127||